# How to add a macron to one letter in ggplot title using labs or alternative function?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to add a macron in my title such that the u looks like this -> ū

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried putting it there as a unicode character? (`\u016b` I think)

Comment: @teunbrand perfect thank you